# Show not existing activities from JOIN (GROUP BY AND SUM)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by

I have a table with multiple data about Work Orders, and there's another table linked to it, where there are a registry of the tasks.

Finally there's a table with Standards Jobs, Depending of 3 factors (Model of Machine, Name of the Component, and Activity), so depending of these three factors, there's different standard times per activity and so on the numbers of technicians per activity.

So the main idea of this query is to show the data group by activities, and show 0 if there's no match with one of the activities listed on the table [@ACTJOB], which one contains the 3 factors involved with standard jobs.

But instead of that, I just get the registry of the data matching the join with the table, excluding not existing activities.

The query:

```
SELECT
WorkOrder.DocNum WorkOrder, -- Here's de unique number of the work order.
WorkOrder.U_INF_Componente, -- The Name of the component being involucred on the WorkOrder
WorkOrder.U_SEI_ModeloEquip, -- Model of the component
COALESCE((SUM(CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,2),REPLACE(Task.U_SEI_Quantity,',','.')))),'0') Quantity, --Total quantity of hours worked by technician
COALESCE((COUNT(DISTINCT Task.U_SEI_TECNICO)),'0') Technicians, --Number of distinct technicians per activity
JOB.Name Activity, -- Name of the activity where the technician were working
StandardJOB.U_INF_HHJOB StandardHH, -- The standard hours per activity
StandardJOB.U_INF_Tecnicos StandardThecnicians -- The standard technicians per activity
FROM OSCL WorkOrder --Table used as call service (Work Orders)
JOIN SCL5 Task ON  WorkOrder.callID = Task.SrvcCallId
JOIN OCLG Activity ON Task.ClgID = Activity.ClgCode
RIGHT JOIN [@ACTJOB] JOB ON JOB.Code=Task.U_INF_JOB AND JOB.U_INF_Estado=1 -- This is the Table containing all the activities.
LEFT JOIN [@STNJOB] StandardJOB ON StandardJOB.U_INF_Activity=Task.U_INF_JOB AND WorkOrder.U_SEI_ModeloEquip=StandardJOB.U_INF_CodModelo AND WorkOrder.U_INF_Componente=StandardJOB.U_INF_IDComp -- In this JOIN we make a cross within Model, Component And Activiry, in order to show the correct standard Job for the matches.
WHERE WorkOrder.DocNum=11605 -- In this field where we specify the work order number.
GROUP BY Task.U_INF_JOB,WorkOrder.DocNum,JOB.Name,StandardJOB.U_INF_Tecnicos,StandardJOB.U_INF_HHJOB,WorkOrder.U_SEI_ModeloEquip,JOB.Code,WorkOrder.U_INF_Componente
```

The [@ACTJOB] Tables which contains Activities:

```
01 DISARMAMENT AND EVALUATION
02 DISARMAMENT REPORT
03 ARMED REPORT
04 PREPARATION OF PARTS AND ASSEMBLY
05 TESTS AND ADJUSTMENTS
06 PAINTING AND PACKAGING PROCESS
08 WASHING
```

What I get with the query:

```
WorkOrder   U_SEI_ModeloEquip       U_INF_Componente    Quantity    Technicians     Activity    StandardHH  StandardTechnicians
11774       793F                    WHEEL AND BRAKE     12.35       3               01          60          3
11774       793F                    WHEEL AND BRAKE     2.67        1               08          10          2
```

What I'm really trying to do:

```
WorkOrder   U_SEI_ModeloEquip       U_INF_Componente    Quantity    Technicians     Activity    StandardHH  StandardTechnicians
11774       793F                    WHEEL AND BRAKE     12.35       3               01          60          3
11774       793F                    WHEEL AND BRAKE     2.67        1               08          10          2
11774       793F                    WHEEL AND BRAKE     0           0               02          2           10
11774       793F                    WHEEL AND BRAKE     0           0               03          2           12
11774       793F                    WHEEL AND BRAKE     0           0               04          1           3
11774       793F                    WHEEL AND BRAKE     0           0               05          1           5
11774       793F                    WHEEL AND BRAKE     0           0               06          2           18
11774       793F                    WHEEL AND BRAKE     0           0               07          1           5
```

I Have already tried with left join, right join, even with UNION ALL, but still stuck on this.

Any help, review, advice. Would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Quantity and technicians come from the task table...left join to the task table instead of the inner join you are currently using?

Comment: To clarify, what you want is to see all records on [@STNJOB] regardless if there matching records on the other tables?

Comment: In other words, i want to show the unexisting values, the ones that not match. So i can show 0 in activities without match.

Comment: So on, i Think functions like "SUM" and "COUNT" dont show the 0 values when you group by. am i wrong?